# c++ int accessor return 0 even if mutator sets properly

Tags: c++, oop, getter-setter, accessor, mutators

I'm stuck at a problem I feel stupid about as it's basically just two lines of code in midst of a 2000 line working OOP script.

Cut to the chase - I have an Entity class which provides various information (name, address, ID). The problem is - even if the ID mutator (setter) sets a proper value (tested with cout and return value), the accessor always returns 0.

```
// ID accessor
int Entity::ID() const {
    return _ID;     
}
// ID mutator
int& Entity::ID( int newID ) {
    if ( newID >= 0 ) {
        _ID = newID;
    }
    return _ID;
}
```

Here are my classes (the ID( int ) method is called in AgencyNetwork::createXXX() and is used in every toStr() method (at the end of each class)):

[Entity.cpp](http://pastie.textmate.org/private/ryonsvsihervgrjyymg), [AgencyNetwork.cpp](http://pastie.textmate.org/private/nk31nx5nw3nwp4arlobfbq), [Agent.cpp](http://pastie.textmate.org/private/ogcgvhjr0kqh7g3be71mg)

**SOLVED:** I forgot to add the ID mutator in every operator=. Thanks to everyone who helped :)

Comment: Any small, self-contained sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: uhm yeah, AgencyNetwork.ccp line 139 is a call to the mutator and Agent.cpp line 275 is a call to the accessor. I hope that's what you ment by sample. Just having the mutator/accessor out "in the wild" wouldn't really make sense I think as it's OOP :)

Comment: it's not good to return `int &` from the 'mutator' member-function. Try return plain `int`.

Comment: DaddyM: thanks for your advice, but I've tried both and nothing changes.

Comment: ok. is your application single-threaded? Is `_ID` = `int _ID;` ?

Comment: DaddyM I don't think it's multithreaded, so I guess it's not ^^ and well _ID is an integer, so I guess _ID == int _ID...

Comment: Header files? Maybe you defined _ID in Entity and *also* (re)defined it in the base classes?

Comment: Johan Lundberg, Aaron McDaid: I declare it in the header file ( http://pastie.textmate.org/private/48ilwb5euavqh9lvtnwg ) but no, I don't redefine it in the baseclass... I just set it to 0 in the constructor, but that shouldn't change anything...

Comment: A "self-contained sample" is code that we could copy, paste, compile, & run. e.g. `int main() {Entity entity;entity.ID(2);cout<<entity.ID();return 0;}` (with nicer formatting of course) along with the entity header and implementation. We can't compile your implementations without the headers.

Comment: 01d55: the example you've shown seems to be working properly - meaning that there's a problem with adding everything to the vectors or something...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I forgot to add ID() in the operator= of every function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most notably, the assignment operator of `Entity` is broken:

```
Entity& Entity::operator= ( const Entity& tocopy ) {
    delete this; // <<< don't do that 

    this -> name ( tocopy.name() );
    this -> address ( tocopy.address() );
    // <<< missing _ID

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Hello Georg,
thanks for pointing out, I forgot this, but sadly, it doesn't fix the problem :/

Comment: Hello Georg!

It's working now - the problem was in the operator= of all the classes, I simply forgot to add ID everywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @Asmodiel, don't forget the other bug. Don't do `delete this`. Also, you should probably not write your own `operator=` in this case. The compiler will provide a sensible default in this case because you are using members which are `string` and `int`. In fact, if the class was designed such that a custom `operator=` is required (`char *` instead of string for example), then I would try to change the design instead!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic. There is plain BUG. So, lets use tracing: trace every 'mutator' call. Make sure that nobody can access the _ID field in other way than through the mutator call. Trace constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor calls also.
Then run your code and follow the trace log.
I'm sure everything will become clear in your case.

NOTE: if your implementation misses some of the member functions mentioned above you should to define them with the bodies consisting of tracer call only.

You shouldn't let the compiler to make any implicit member function generation in order to be sure that you've the full control of you class and particularly the `_ID` field.